# List all channel listeners for ipcRenderer in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

We have an electron app. We add / remove listeners using

```js
const funct = () => {}
ipcRenderer.on('channel', funct);

// later...
ipcRenderer.removeListener('channel', funct)
```

We want to make sure no event handlers leak in our application. How would we query `ipcRenderer` for **all** channel listeners?

Answer (score 2):

- `ipcRenderer.eventNames()` lists all channels that have listeners
- `ipcRenderer.rawListeners(channel)` lists all listeners for a particular channel

```
ipcRenderer.eventNames().forEach(channel => ipcRenderer.rawListeners(channel))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have way to query for all channels at once. Closest thing is

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererremovealllistenerschannel

`ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners(channel)`

That you can remove all listeners to specific channels. You still have to manage list of channels by yourself.

Comment: I don't want to remove the listeners, just to know whether or not they are there.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain` are Node [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter)s, you can use the base API for event management.

[`eventNames`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_eventnames) can be used to query every "channel", and [`removeAllListeners`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removealllisteners_eventname) can remove every listener for one channel

So this code will remove every listener from the emitter instance

```
ipcRenderer.eventNames().forEach(n => {
  ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners(n)
})
```

---

However, you should not do this actually! (from node docs)

> Note that it is bad practice to remove listeners added elsewhere in
>   the code, particularly when the EventEmitter instance was created by
>   some other component or module (e.g. sockets or file streams).

Comment: I don't want to remove the listeners, just to know whether or not they are there. However, `eventNames()` is really helpful. I put everything I learned together and created an answer. Thank you for your help!